# Stratified train/test-split with guaranteed inclusion of small classes on strongly imbalanced datasets

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I am working with large-scale, imbalanced datasets where I need to pick a stratified training set. However, even if the dataset is strongly imbalanced, I still need to ensure that at least every label class is included at least once in the training set. sklearns train_test_split or StratifiedShuffleSplit will not "guarantee" this inclusion.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = np.arange(100).reshape((50, 2))
y = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=4, random_state=42, stratify=y)

print(X_train, y_train)
```

The result is

```
[[80 81]
 [48 49]
 [18 19]
 [30 31]] [2, 2, 1, 1]
```

So the label classes 3 and 4 are not included in this training split. Given the absolute train_size=4, these two classes are not large enough to be included. For a strictly stratified split, this is correct.
However, for the smaller classes, I need at least make sure that the algorithm "has seen the label class". Therefore, I need some kind of softening of the stratification principle, and have some kind of proportional inclusion of smaller classes.
I have written quite some code to achieve this, which removes smaller classes first, and then handles them separately with a proportional split. However, when removed, this will also influence train_test_split due to the changes in class amounts/total size.

Is there any simple function/algorithm to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [`sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html)? Try setting `n_folds` to be less than or equal to the number of members in the least populated class. If you have, then I can only recommend using under-/over-sampling methods from [`imbalanced-learn`](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/index.html).

Comment: Thank your very much for the suggestions. Unfortunately, StratifiedKFold in that case with n_fold=2 will be a 50:50 split, but does not resolve the problem.
I looked at imbalanced-learn and found that a RandomUnderSampler with an own implementation of a sampling_strategy using an exponential decrease would solve this problem. However, this own implementation is exactly what I have today using an exponential decrease across the classes (I have used sklearns resample for this). So no real simplification here...